# Localize particular points in an array with OpenCV

Tags: arrays, opencv

I have a 2D array (cv::MAT), and I want to find out the indexes of all the elements with non-zero value. In other words, [x, y] = find(A ~= 0)?

Can OpenCV return result in cv::Point format?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation, it's all there !

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html

You'll use basic element access to `cv::Mat`

```
M.at<double>(i,j) += 1.f;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I have very carefully check the documentation on basic structures, and I don't think there is a specific function for my question. Are you suggesting me to do a loop and then find out all the indices of non-zero values? That is easy but not classy. Actually in Matlab, we can use [x, y] = find(A ~= 0) to achieve it. But does OpenCV have a similar function?

Comment: There are much better ways to find out all indices with 0, but it depends in which way you want to continue to use that data. From your question it seemed you're interested in a list of points. You could for example apply a threshold or binary operator function over the Matrix, with the resulting cv::Mat having all points set to a certain value, but this would only make sense if you want to re-use that matrix in another method (e.g. as a filter mask). Take a look at `cv::compare` or one of the `bitwise_OPERATOR` methods like `bitwise_and`.